# Change device passcode from my swift app(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

i have done lots of RND, and till didn't found any reference and link for start coding for change device passcode from my swift app, i don't need code directly but just need some starting guidance or any reference link, so from that link or  reference, i can make this functionality work in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only authenticate with touch id or passcode , but you have no permission / Apis that can change the current passcode of the device , only you can alert the user and navigate to settings

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not possible with iOS